# Container element doesn't update it's width / position when a transform CSS animation is being applied to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a simple "ticker" consisting of a moving container, and a JavaScript function that doesn't allow child elements to go over the limit.

My intention is that by switching the first element to the last position at an appropiate time, the container will stay *frozen*, and thus forming a simple ticker.

[This is a visualization of my problem](http://codepen.io/ajf-/pen/fLvot/)

I'm not getting the result I expected. I must be doing something wrong.

Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: Can you explain the results you expect?

Comment: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do (just differently): http://wmh.github.io/jquery-scrollbox/#demo5